# Unwanted SalesForce Contacts

Tags: mobile, salesforce-for-outlook, data-synchronization

I have a new Samsung Galaxy 4. All my company's SalesForce contacts (3000+) transferred to my contacts. What is the best way to get rid of them and still keep my regular Outlook contacts?

Comment: What mobile program are you using to access Salesforce contacts?

Comment: Did these contacts arrive through the Salesforce for Outlook connector and a sync to your device? Is your goal to retain all of the SFDC contacts in Outlook on your desktop and only have your own personal contact list synchronized with your phone?

Comment: greenstork: Mictrosoft Exchange.

Mark Pond: I hope I understand your question. We have Microsoft Exchange - Outlook that is integrated with Sales Force. The goal is for each individual to just sync their own Outlook contacts - not the 3000+ contacts in SalesForce.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did and I hope this works:

Go to Set Up 
Under Desktop Integration, click on Salesforce for Outlook 
Click on a user's name (hyperlink) 
Under the "Data Set" section, click Edit 
Under Sync, check "Selected Contacts" and choose "User's Records" for contacts and any additional filters you want.